# asp.net core 7 blazor them identity

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I added the identity to aps.net core 7 blazor app. But the Identity pages do you use the out of the box Balzor theme.

How can I configure the asp.net core 7 identity to use the Balzor out of the box Balzor theme?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't.  You'll have to modify the scaffolded pages to match the theme.  ALTHOUGH, I reckon if you google around, somebody has probably already done this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for asp.net core 7 is not too difficult.

The identity pages use the layout in the file /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml.

So you need to make _Layout.cshtml file behave the same as the /Shared/_Host.cshtml and /Shared/MaintLayout.razor working together.

One difficulty is cshtml do not seem to load the Blazor-generated css files, so I had to manully add the generated styles to the /wwwroot/css/site.css. If you are not using Blazor-generated css files, then you do not need to update the site.css file.

Note the custom css at the bottom of the site.css file:

```css
/*  fix top row background color for identity pages*/
.top-row.auth {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

/* fix sidebar no displaying */
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapse {
         Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens 
        display: block !important;
    }

    .nav-scrollable {
         Allow sidebar to scroll for tall menus 
        height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

See a working version on github: https://github.com/MSIH/BlazorThemeIdentity

1. From the /Shared/_Host.cshtml copy the HTML content

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorThemeIdentity.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Into /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml overwriting the HTML content

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using YOURappName.Shared


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorThemeIdentity.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

3. From /Shared/MaintLayout.razor copy the HTML content between the

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

4. Into /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml overwriting the line `<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />`

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using YOURappName.Shared


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorThemeIdentity.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
   @* overwrite or comment out <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />  *@
    <div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <NavMenu /> 
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
             <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
          @Body          
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

6. Update code to reneder compoments in cshtml pages

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using YOURappName.Shared


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorThemeIdentity.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
   @* overwrite or comment out <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />  *@
    <div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
     @* overwrite or comment out <NavMenu /> *@
         <component type="typeof(NavMenu )" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            @* overwrite or comment out  <LoginDisplay /> *@
            <component type="typeof(LoginDisplay)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
          @* @Body *@
          @RenderBody()
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

7. cshtml files do not seem to load blazor css files, so you need to copy the Blazor generated style into the /wwwroot/css/site.css file

```css
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');



html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1:focus {
    outline: none;
}

a, .btn-link {
    color: #0071c1;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn-link.nav-link:focus, .form-control:focus, .form-check-input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem white, 0 0 0 0.25rem #258cfb;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}

.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.validation-message {
    color: red;
}

#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

    #blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.75rem;
        top: 0.5rem;
    }

.blazor-error-boundary {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 1rem/1.8rem, #b32121;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3.7rem;
    color: white;
}

    .blazor-error-boundary::after {
        content: "An error has occurred."
    }

/* start from Shared/MainLayout.css */

.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}

.top-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

    .top-row a, .top-row .btn-link {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
    }

        .top-row a:first-child {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }

@media (max-width: 640.98px) {
    .top-row:not(.auth) {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-row.auth {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .top-row a, .top-row .btn-link {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .page {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-row, article {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
}
/* end from Shared/MainLayout.css */

/* start from Shared/NavMenu.css */
.navbar-toggler {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.top-row {
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.oi {
    width: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    top: -2px;
}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

    .nav-item:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item:last-of-type {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item a {
        color: #d7d7d7;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 3rem;
    }

        .nav-item a.active {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
            color: white;
        }

        .nav-item a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            color: white;
        }


/* end from Shared/NavMenu.css */

/* fix top row background color for identity pages*/
.top-row.auth {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

/* fix sidebar no displaying */
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapse {
         Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens 
        display: block !important;
    }

    .nav-scrollable {
         Allow sidebar to scroll for tall menus 
        height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```